# GPU instances on AWS Batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gpu, autoscaling, aws-batch

I am trying to get GPU instances to work on AWS Batch, and I cannot get batch to create an auto-scaling group for me.

I already got the quota for G-family servers, Got my container image to work inside my local docker GPU environment, even measured its resource usage to check if it fits inside the instance.

```
resource "aws_batch_compute_environment" "compute" {
  compute_environment_name = "terraform_compute"
  compute_resources {
    instance_role      = aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs_instance_role.arn
    instance_type      = ["g5.2xlarge"]
    max_vcpus          = 128
    min_vcpus          = 0
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.batch.id]
    subnets            = data.aws_subnet_ids.default.ids
    type               = "EC2"
  }
  service_role = aws_iam_role.aws_batch_service_role.arn
  type         = "MANAGED"
  depends_on   = [aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.aws_batch_service_role]
}

resource "aws_batch_job_queue" "job_queue" {
  name                 = "terraform_batch_job_queue"
  state                = "ENABLED"
  priority             = 1
  compute_environments = [aws_batch_compute_environment.compute.arn]
  depends_on           = [aws_batch_compute_environment.compute]
}

resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "process" {
  name = "terraform_processor"
  type = "container"
  timeout {
    attempt_duration_seconds = "120"
  }

  platform_capabilities = ["EC2"]

  container_properties = <<EOF
{
  "image": "455475906353.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/hello-repository:latest",
  "command": ["python", "main.py"],
  "jobRoleArn": "${aws_iam_role.task_role.arn}",
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "JOB_ID",
      "value": "0000000000000000"
    },
    {
      "name": "TIME",
      "value": "0000"
    },
    {
      "name": "INDEX",
      "value": "0000"
    }
  ],
  "resourceRequirements": [
    {
      "value": "8",
      "type": "VCPU"
    },
    {
      "value": "32768",
      "type": "MEMORY"
    },
    {
      "value": "1",
      "type": "GPU"
    }
  ],
  "logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awslogs"
  }
}
EOF
}
```

this is my terraform script, and what I cannot understand is that everything works if I just set the instance type to a CPU-based instance.

Also, I checked the launch templates, and those were created.

Comment: Are you getting insufficient capacity errors?